# Не работает addOnScrollListener RecyclerAdapter. Как обновить данные в адаптере?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно сделать infinite scroll. В примерах с `listview` у меня работает `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`. Но вот в  `RecyclerAdapter` почему-о не хочет.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
cardview.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager) {
    @Override
    public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
       new GetListData().execute();
       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас и для ListView не должно работать. Вы вызываете notifyDataSetChanged слишеом рано, до окончания задачи. А когда данные придут, список не обновится.

Вам надо вызывать notifyDataSetChanged в onPostExecute вашей задачи

Answer (score 0):

В итоге помогла вот така конструкция (вынесенная на выполнение после загрузки данных):

```
mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(newData);
cardview.swapAdapter(mAdapter,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя вызывать подобные методы пока работает внутренний механизм RecyclerView. Обновлять нужно по каким-то событиям. Например мы получили ответ из сети, или из Лоадера.
В качестве костыля поможет:

```
cardview.post(new Runnable() {
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
});
```

В этом случае метод выполнится вне метода Recycler-а и ничего не "сломается".